# can't get setw to line up

Tags: c++, setw

I'm not sure how to go about lining this up better. I thought by using `L = name.length();` and subtracting that from the `setw` it would line up better but nope. I have `name` and `ID` set correctly but I can't seem to get the rest to line up.  These are `floats` btw.

```
for (int z=0; z<i ;z++){

  if( EInfo[z].valid >0){

    string name = employee[z].getName();
    int L = name.length();

    payReportObj << fixed << setprecision (2)  <<  endl;

      payReportObj  << setw(3) << employee[z].getID()
                  << setw(36)
                  << employee[z].getName()
                  << setw(30-L) << "$" << setw(4) << EInfo[z].grossPaySE
                  << setw(25) << "$" << setw(4) << EInfo[z].taxSE
                  << setw(15) << "$" << setw(4) << EInfo[z].insuranceSE
                  << setw(25) << "$" << setw(4) << EInfo[z].netPaySE;
```

I'm attempting to get it more like this...
[image: Want I'm trying to go for]

This is what I have... [image: This is what I have.]

Comment: Could you provide an example of the way you want the data to be lay out?

Comment: Is that a variable-width font? Seriously?

Comment: If this is indeed not a monospaced font, you can try using tab characters to line up the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `setw(30-L)`  with `setw(30)`.  And this:

```
int L = name.length();
```

is not needed. If you want to right-align numbers, use `std::right`.

It seams that you opened your output file in nodepad with proportional font. You won't see columns aligned with proportional font even if they are.  Change font to fixed or type in your terminal `type output.txt`.